# Is HeadJS still 'logical' when you only have 1 minified JS file?

Tags: javascript, performance, lazy-loading

Does it make sense to use HeadJS when you only want to load in 1 (minified) file that contains all the scripts..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not make any sense as you are only loading one single resource...Adding the HeadJS will make your app getting one more resource...thus increasing the response time...

Include the minified JS at the end of the file and do not add the HeadJs...That would work fine...

Comment: Then the next question: One big minified file vs a couple of minified files through HeadJS?

Comment: Any ways...the Js files if included at the bottom and if they are minified they would not make much difference....while adding one more resource can make a difference...You get wide variations at the [headJs](http://headjs.com/test/headjs.html) as well...a few hit and trials will give you those variations...In my opinion if its only a single resource its better to avoid the headjs and an extra resouce getting included..